# C# Drawing line between ellipses

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am making a program that involves drawing lines between given "ellipses". When I try to run the emulator, and the mouse enters the first "ellipse", I get an exception handling issue with the casting of ellipse to point. I could do it a different way if it would be recommended, all I need is to be able to draw a line between given coordinates, each coordinate pertaining to the respective ellipse. Help?

```
    Point old;
    List<String> DrawnLines = new List<String>();
    private void CheckPoint(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Point selectedEllipse = (Point)sender;


        if (old.Equals(null))
        {
            old.Equals(sender);
        }
        else
        {
            if (selectedEllipse.Equals(old) == false) 
    //This is a check to make sure that a different point has been hit
            {
                System.Windows.Shapes.Line connectline = new System.Windows.Shapes.Line();
                connectline.Width = 10;
                connectline.X1 = old.X;
                connectline.Y1 = old.Y;
                connectline.X2 = selectedEllipse.X; //.Margin.Left;
                connectline.Y2 = selectedEllipse.Y; //.Margin.Top;
                drawCanvas.Children.Add(connectline);
                DrawnLines.Add((old.ToString() + " " + selectedEllipse.ToString()));
                DrawnLines.Add((selectedEllipse.ToString() + " " + old.ToString()));
                old = (Point)sender;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, an ellipse is not a point, so casting one as the other will of course throw an error. Maybe you want the *center* point of an ellipse.

Comment: If the ellipse is not tilted, the center point should be at `x = ellipse.width / 2` and `y = ellipse.height / 2` relative to the ellipse itself. So you need the position of the ellipse (usually the position of the top left corner of the enclosing rectangle) and add those x and y values to the previously calculated ones to get the center point of the ellipse relative to the area you're drawing it in.